# Bada: CustomItem in ListView

Tags: bada

I want to create a  CustomItem for my ListView and i have a problem with my String text. I try to put a string with the character "\n" for line change.

I create my String like that:

```
  String fullName ="First Name: ";
  fullName.Append(firstName);//one string variable
  fullName.Append("\n");
  fullName.Append("Last Name: ");
  fullName.Append(lastName);//one string variable
```

I want lastName and FirstName showed up in different lines.

i put this string in my custom Item like that:
pCitem->AddElement(Osp::Graphics::Rectangle(10,-30,430,150),index,fullName,35,Osp::Graphics::Color::COLOR_GREEN,Osp::Graphics::Color::COLOR_RED,true);

(API here : http://developer.bada.com/help_2.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppapireference.help/classOsp_1_1Ui_1_1Controls_1_1CustomItem.html).

My problem is that firstName and lastName didn't showed up in different lines. How i can fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The **AddElement()** method that you used only allows you to insert a single-line string.
For multi-line strings you have to create an **EnrichedText** which supports text on
multiple lines and use the:

```
result CustomItem::AddElement (const Osp::Graphics::Rectangle &rect, 
                               int elementId, 
                               const Osp::Graphics::EnrichedText &text)
```

method to insert it into your **CustomItem**.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add **two string**, one with first name and another with last name as shows below. Where **Rectangle()** functions contain different coordinates.

```
String firstName(L"First Name: ");
firstName.Append("first name");

String lastName(L"Last Name: ");
lastName.Append("last name");

pCitem->AddElement(Rectangle(10,30,430,150),index,firstName,35,Osp::Graphics::Color::COLOR_GREEN,Osp::Graphics::Color::COLOR_RED,true);
pCitem->AddElement(Rectangle(10,65,430,150),index,lastName,35,Osp::Graphics::Color::COLOR_GREEN,Osp::Graphics::Color::COLOR_RED,true);
```